# Using local storage or session storage keep collapse item-1 class show/not show

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap-5

I have issue with keeping my callapse item after refresh open or closed.
I using bootstrap 5.
To see accordion item see, need add `show` in the class

```
<div role="tabpanel" data-bs-parent="#accordion-1" class="accordion-collapse collapse show item-1" id="1">
```

My html code:

```
<div id="row" class="row gaps">
    <div id="col-3" class="col-lg-3">
        <div role="tablist" class="accordion" id="accordion-1">
            <div class="accordion-item visible">
                <h2 role="tab" class="accordion-header mb-0"><button data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#accordion-1 .item-1" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="accordion-1 .item-1" class="accordion-button" style="font-family: Alata, sans-serif;">1th</button></h2>
                <div role="tabpanel" data-bs-parent="#accordion-1" class="accordion-collapse collapse show item-1" id="1">
                    <div class="accordion-body"><span style="font-family: Alata, sans-serif;font-size: 22px;"> random text</span></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div role="tablist" class="accordion" id="accordion-4">
            <div class="accordion-item visible">
                <h2 role="tab" class="accordion-header mb-0"><button data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#accordion-4 .item-1" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="accordion-4 .item-1" class="accordion-button" style="font-family: Alata, sans-serif;">  2th</button></h2>
                <div role="tabpanel" data-bs-parent="#accordion-4" class="accordion-collapse collapse show item-1 show" id="2">
                    <div class="accordion-body"><span style="font-family: Alata, sans-serif;font-size: 22px;"> random text 2</span>
                        <div class="d-grid gap-2"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="col-3" class="col-lg-3">
        <div role="tablist" class="accordion" id="accordion-2">
            <div class="accordion-item visible">
                <h2 role="tab" class="accordion-header mb-0"><button data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#accordion-2 .item-1" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="accordion-2 .item-1" class="accordion-button" style="font-family: Alata, sans-serif;">3 th</button></h2>
                <div role="tabpanel" data-bs-parent="#accordion-2" class="accordion-collapse collapse show item-1" id="3">
                    <div class="accordion-body"><span style="font-family: Alata, sans-serif;font-size: 22px;"> random text 3</span>
                        <div class="d-grid gap-2"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div role="tablist" class="accordion" id="accordion-3">
            <div class="accordion-item visible">
                <h2 role="tab" class="accordion-header mb-0"><button data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#accordion-3 .item-1" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="accordion-3 .item-1" class="accordion-button" style="font-family: Alata, sans-serif;"> 4th</button></h2>
                <div role="tabpanel" data-bs-parent="#accordion-3" class="accordion-collapse collapse show item-1" id="4">
                    <div class="accordion-body"><span style="font-family: Alata, sans-serif;font-size: 22px;"> random text 4</span>
                        <div class="d-grid gap-2"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then I press on  `4th` button for example i can hide it. Visually looks like this.
[image]

So I want too keep it after refreshing the page.

I try to

```
<script>
    // Open/close the collapse panels based on history
    var storage  = $.localStorage;

    $('.collapse').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
        storage.remove('open_' + this.id);
    });

    $('.collapse').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
        storage.set('open_' + this.id, true);
    });

    $('.collapse').each(function () {
        // Default close unless saved as open
        if (storage.get('open_' + this.id) == true) {
            $(this).collapse('show');
        }
    });
</script>
```

But what not working for me.

Please, can you give some tips how to solve my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`localStorage` is not defined inside `jQuery` but inside `Window` so you should access it as `window.localStorage` or just `localStorage` but not as `$.localStorage`

Comment: if page will be use on mobile browser, it will work? If not maybe better use session storage?

Comment: `localStorage` is not dependent on the device - mobile or not

Comment: With what, still not saving, maybe problem is with corrects div's?

Comment: You probably have more incorrect spots in your code ... generally local storage doesn't have methods named `get`, `set` and `remove` but `getItem` and `setItem` and `removeItem`. You don't have provided a copy of your code which might be fixed i.e. these events you have handlers for are never fired and e.t.c.  The way you provide your case for resolving is the main reason of no interest of helping. Your case is not difficult, but you gave a partial code and no one can give you a great help based on that.

Comment: thanks for tips, its working now.